# Payplug api authentication failed

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

i'm trying to create a payment with payplug api, i copy and paste the code from documentation to my site, but always have this exception:

Authentication failed because the remote party has closed the transport stream.

This is the code that i use

```
Configuration.SecretKey = "sk_test_11111111111111111111";

    var paymentData = new Dictionary<string, dynamic>
    {
        { "amount", 3300 },
        { "currency", "EUR" },
        { "customer", new Dictionary<string, object>
            {
                { "email", "john.watson@example.net" },
                { "first_name", "John" },
                { "last_name", "Watson" }
            }
        },
        { "hosted_payment", new Dictionary<string, object>
            {
                { "return_url", "https://example.net/success?id=42710" },
                { "cancel_url", "https://example.net/cancel?id=42710" }
            }
        },
        { "notification_url", "https://example.net/notifications?id=42710" },
        { "metadata", new Dictionary<string, object>
            {
                { "customer_id", "42710" }
            }
        },
        { "save_card", false },
        { "force_3ds", true }
    };
            var payment = Payment.Create(paymentData);
```

This is the stack trace

```
[IOException: Authentication failed because the remote party has closed 

the transport stream.]
   System.Net.Security.SslState.StartReadFrame(Byte[] buffer, Int32 readBytes, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest) +6815104
   System.Net.Security.SslState.StartReceiveBlob(Byte[] buffer, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest) +132
   System.Net.Security.SslState.CheckCompletionBeforeNextReceive(ProtocolToken message, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest) +281
   System.Net.Security.SslState.StartSendBlob(Byte[] incoming, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest) +49
   System.Net.Security.SslState.ForceAuthentication(Boolean receiveFirst, Byte[] buffer, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest) +162
   System.Net.Security.SslState.ProcessAuthentication(LazyAsyncResult lazyResult) +542
   System.Net.TlsStream.CallProcessAuthentication(Object state) +42
   System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx) +228
   System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx) +21
   System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state) +64
   System.Net.TlsStream.ProcessAuthentication(LazyAsyncResult result) +778
   System.Net.TlsStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size) +52
   System.Net.PooledStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size) +21
   System.Net.ConnectStream.WriteHeaders(Boolean async) +388

[WebException: The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send.]
   System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetRequestStream(TransportContext& context) +916
   System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetRequestStream() +13
   Payplug.Core.Service.Request(String method, Uri uri, String data, String authorizationHeader) +672
   Payplug.Core.Service.Post(Uri uri, String data) +27
   Payplug.Payment.CreateRaw(String payment) +56
   Payplug.Payment.Create(Dictionary`2 payment) +34
   p_payplug.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in d:\inetpub\tredwebcom\p\payplug.aspx.cs:40
   System.Web.Util.CalliEventHandlerDelegateProxy.Callback(Object sender, EventArgs e) +51
   System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e) +95
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +59
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +678
```

Answer (score 0):

What is the url of your website?

I believe you get this message because your server is not compatible with TLS 1.2 protocol.

With PHP, this means you should update your version of OpenSSL and libcurl but with the .NET I don't know what the equivalent is.

Therefore, you should investigate about TLS and your CACERT and upgrade the required components. I guess you will have to upgrade to .net version 4.6 for that.

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved by adding this before the request

System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls;